Mongoose error while trying to create a new document

here is the mongoose version im using "mongoose": "^8.3.2"
and here is the full code

import mongoose from "mongoose";
import User from "./script.js";

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/appdb")


const run = async()=>{
  try {
    const user = new User({name:"someone", age:55})
    user.save()
    console.log(user)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  }
}
run()


script.js

import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
})

export default mongoose.model("User" ,userSchema)

the error
the error

There is a common Node ipv6 hurdle you need to be aware of when using mongoose. The easiest way to overcome it is to use the 127.0.0.1 system loopback address if your server is running on localhost via ipv4.
You may also want to await for mongoose to connect so that you can see any connection issues and only execute your run() function if it's successful like so:
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import User from "./script.js";

const run = async()=>{
  try {
    const user = new User({name:"someone", age:55})
    await user.save() //< add await here
    console.log(user)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  }
}

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/appdb")
.then(async ()=>{
   console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
   await run(); //, add await here
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log('Error when connecting: ', err);
})


tnx guys it worked!
